# Alternative to OpenBiblio

Tags: looking-for-a-script, lamp

Are there any good open source alternatives to [OpenBiblio](http://obiblio.sourceforge.net/) that can run on a hosting package without root access to the server?

I have tried [Koha](http://koha-community.org/) and [Evergreen](http://www.open-ils.org/), but they need root access and are not compatibility with my hosting package. Are there any good open source ones that can run with PHP and MySQL and are community maintained and updated?

Answer (score 0):

[phpmylibrary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmylibrary/) "is a PHP MySQL Library automation application".